# How can I filter author Ids out of this json?

Tags: python, json

I'm specifically trying to get the id out of "author" to write it to a json file, But I have no idea how to filter out the ids and then write them to the file. Im kinda new to this

```
[
    {
    "id":"865170257588125696",
    "content":"<@862323352869797948> I set your AFK: yes",
    "channel_id":"859115914444537876",
    "author":{
        "id":"155149108183695360",
        "username":"Dyno",
        "discriminator":"3861",
        }
    },
    {
    "id":"865170254677409812",
    "content":"?afk yes",
    "channel_id":"859115914444537876",
    "author":{
        "id":"862323352869797948",
        "username":"zz2w2wfff2",
        "discriminator":"2401"
        }
    },
    {
    "id":"865170247349567488",
    "content":"Meh",
    "channel_id":"859115914444537876",
    "author":{
        "id":"862323352869797948",
        "username":"zz2w2wfff2",
        "discriminator":"2401"
        }
    }
]
```

This is all I have:

```py
r = requests.get("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/" + channelid + "/messages?limit=50", headers=headers)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        authorid = r.json()[0]["author"]["id"]
        for authorid in r.text:
            print(authorid)
```

All that did was show gibberish when I ran it.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Have you written any code to try and iterate over those messages in the list? Or to access the author ID within?

Comment: I tried
`authorid = r.json()[0]["author"]["id"]

for authorid in r.text:

     print(authorid)`

But its probably very wrong and Im completely clueless

(the r.json is the json in the post)

Comment: Please show that code, then.

Comment: uh it should be in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, this should get you going. You don't need to access the `r` response anymore after you've parsed it using `r.json()`:

```
r = requests.get("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/" + channelid + "/messages?limit=50", headers=headers)
r.raise_for_status()
data = r.json()
for message in data:
    print(message["author"]["id"])
```

Comment: tysm, cant believe the solution was this easy all along